# Symfony form is using get method

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I am new to symfony, I have just created the html form in my view twig file, I have also mentioned form method=post but every-time when I submit the form its using get method.I am using php versio 7.0 and symfony version 3.3.10
Following is my html form in register.html.twig file:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}
    <div class="main-body">
        <div class="container">
                <h1 class="title-heading">Identificação</h1>
                    <div class="cadastro-form">
                        <form id="register_form" role="form" action="user/register/step-2" method="post"    >
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <input type="hidden" name ="user[id]" value="user[ids]">
                            <h1 class="title-heading">Faça seu cadastro</h1>
                            <div class="radio-btns">
                                <p>Tipo de Pessoa:</p>
                            <p>
                                <input type="radio" id="test1" name="user[user_type]" checked>
                                <label for="test1">Física</label>
                            </p> 
                              <p>
                                <input type="radio" id="test2" name="user[user_type]" value=>
                                <label for="test2">Jurídica</label>
                              </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group required">
                                    <label class="control-label">
                                        <!-- Nome -->
                                        Name
                                    </label>
                                        <input type="text" name="user[first_name]" class="form-control" placeholder="Ex:Igor" >
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group required">
                                    <label class="control-label">
                                        <!-- Sobrenome -->
                                        Last name
                                    </label>
                                        <input type="text" name="user[last_name]" class="form-control" placeholder="Ex:Souza">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div class="form-group required">
                                <label class="control-label">
                                    Ponto de referência
                                </label>
                                    <input type="text" name="user[reference_point]" class="form-control" placeholder="Ex: Próximo a estação">
                            </div>

                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-12">

                                    <div class="form-check">

                                     <input type="checkbox" name="user[promotional_emails]" id="test" />
                                    <label for="test"> Desejo receber e-mails de ofertas promocionais do IASP</label>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <a href="/" class="button-border" type="button">Voltar</a>
                                    <input class="button-filled" type="submit" name="fazer_cadastro" value="Fazer cadastro">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </form>


        </div>

    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Below is my UserController code:

```
public function showAction($slug, $userid=null)
{

    $userid = 19;
    $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $repository2=$em->getRepository('AppBundle:User');
    $userInfo = $repository2->findOneBy(array('id'=>$userid));

    return $this->render('user/register.html.twig', [
        'base_dir' => realpath($this->getParameter('kernel.project_dir')).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,
        'user' => $userInfo
    ]);
}
```

And when I submit the form its using get method. However, I have checked with inspect element its showing method=post as shown in the below screenshot:
[image]

Kindly help me with the solution. Thanks

Comment: seems like you got problem with register action, but why you posted showAction from controller which seems is not related with problem?

Comment: Hi, register is coming from showAction this is the routing  @Route("/user/{slug}", name="user_show")

Comment: and since you are using symfony why won't you use symfony Form component?

Comment: So click on the network tab of your inspector and verify that GET is being used in place of POST.  Seems very unlikely unless you have some javascript magic going on.